# Generate referral link for each user

Tags: ios, app-store

I am searching for a way to achieve this. I want something like Dropbox, each user(**say X**) can create their own unique referral link and send them to their friends (**say Y**). Now if **Y** `installs` the application I want to reward **X** with some points. Is there any site that can help me in this or any other way to do this. For now I don't know what to look for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do something like that with an iPhone \ IPad app. There's no way knowing from where the user that just installed your app came from. It's possible in android using google analytics but Apple  doesn't aprove such a thing.